# How to connect with pgAdmin3 in the AWS PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, pgadmin

I cannot to connect with AWS postgres remote by my local machine.

I definitely not connect to postgres remote in AWS server.

I already follow another topics but I still confuse why don't connect anywhere?

.

In my remote server I follow this 3 steps:

1) I change the port of remote database to `5434`.

2) In `postgresql.conf` file I set "*" to `listen_addresses` flag.

In `pg_hba.conf` file I set `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` attributes

3) I restart postgres service of remote server

PgAdmin3 error output:

`05:17:44 PM: Error: SSH error: Error when starting up SSH session with error code -8 [Unable to exchange encryption keys]`

I have not succeeded to access postgres remote to the AWS RDBMS. I follow this instructions: http://imperialwicket.com/aws-install-postgresql-90-on-amazon-linux

.

**Screenshots:**

I follow all topics below:

[image]

.

I configurate pgAdmin3 to access as below:

- `MY_IP_HERE` I set with AWS ipv4
- `my_user_here` I set with my database user

.

[image]

.

[image]

.

And then I try to connect with my remote database with HTTP Tunnel

.

[image]

.

And I fail

.

[image]

.

Sometimes this popup error appears in pgAdmin3:

```
ASSERT INFO:
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/strvararg.h(456): assert "(argtype & (wxFormatStringSpecifier<T>::value)) == argtype" failed in wxArgNormalizer(): format specifier doesn't match argument type

BACKTRACE:
[1] wxMBConvUTF32LE::~wxMBConvUTF32LE()
[2] char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag)
[3] char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag)
[4] char* std::string::_S_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag)
[5] wxListEvent::~wxListEvent()
[6] wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const
[7] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)
[8] wxEvtHandler::SearchDynamicEventTable(wxEvent&)
[9] wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&)
[10] wxEvtHandler::DoTryChain(wxEvent&)
[11] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)
[12] wxWindowBase::TryAfter(wxEvent&)
[13] wxEvtHandler::SafelyProcessEvent(wxEvent&)
[14] wxToolBarBase::OnLeftClick(int, bool)
[15] g_signal_emit_valist
[16] g_signal_emit_by_name
[17] g_signal_emit_valist
[18] g_signal_emit
[19] g_closure_invoke
[20] g_signal_emit_valist
[21] g_signal_emit
[22] g_closure_invoke
[23] g_signal_emit_valist
[24] g_signal_emit
[25] gtk_propagate_event
[26] gtk_main_do_event
[27] g_main_context_dispatch
[28] g_main_loop_run
[29] gtk_main
[30] wxGUIEventLoop::DoRun()
[31] wxEventLoopBase::Run()
[32] wxAppConsoleBase::MainLoop()
[33] wxEntry(int&, wchar_t**)
[34] __libc_start_main
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I find a solution (for Linux).

Using the following command line:

```
sudo ssh -N -L 1234:yourrdsendpointname.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 ec2-user@56.78.123.45 -i yourkeyfile.pem
```

In this example **1234** is a local port (available in local host), **yourrdsendpointname.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com** is the end point of your RDS database in aws, **ec2-user** is the default user of the ec2 instance that's has permission to connect to rds database,**56.78.123.45** is the public ip of the ec2 instance and **yourkeyfile.pem** is your key to access the ec2 instance.

When your run this command, you can access your database in local host and port 1234 using pgAdmin or psql command (note that's this command should be running in the terminal to keep the tunnel open).

To more explanation you can go here.

https://medium.com/@michalisantoniou6/connect-to-an-aws-rds-using-an-ssh-tunnel-22f3bd597924

Comment: I post more details about the error with RDS instances too.

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues first lets will port forward the database RDS in your local machine. First try:

**sudo ssh -N -L 6969:ENDPOINTNAMERDS:5432 USER@[PUBLIC_IP_EC2] -i KEYFILE.pem**

(5432 is the port of RDS database in AWS, 6969 is a aleatory port avaliable in your machine)

Keep the process of this command running (if ok you'll no see outputs).

After that you shoul'd connect in database, using the host name: **localhost** and port **6969** (The command ssh should'be runing and without outputs)

Comment: I got it but I received a `time out` answer in PgAdmin3 and in linux console I have empty output.

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues if you received time out you need check your security group of RDS instance (the port 5432 should be open), check if the RDS database are configured to listening in the port 5432, if its another port only change 5432 to this another port.

Comment: For default AWS Beanstalk create RDS instances pointing out to port 5432 and yeah, it's open and running `Publicly accessible: yes`

Answer (score 0):

@Nielson I try to connect on linux console with SSH Tunnel.

`5433` is postgres local port of my machine

`$ sudo lsof -i :5433`

`COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pgadmin3 1329 paneladm   15u  IPv4 1534908      0t0  TCP debian:56894->ec2-[MY_IP].[ZONE].compute.amazonaws.com:5433 (SYN_SENT)`

And below of the terminal is empty.

In PgAdmin3 has no connect too.

I have not idea how to make a external connection with RDS too because the default group allow external connections already.

[image]

References:

[AWS RDS -
 Connecting to a DB Instance Running the PostgreSQL Database Engine](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html)

[SSH tunneling. "bind Address already in use"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175004&p=12792329#post12792329)